# JBoss 5.1.0GA "user null is NOT authenticated" issue

Tags: java, security, jboss, null

I have a jBoss 5.1.0-GA running a server, it was running find. But I copied whole jboss to another server, (by using tar). When I start new jBoss, it give a "user null is NOT authenticated", here is the stack trace

```
[ExceptionUtil] 
ConnectionFactoryEndpoint[jboss.messaging.connectionfactory:service=ConnectionFactory] 
createFailoverConnectionDelegate [nb-z2y983bh-1-4b8983bh-kwpr33-100j3]
javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: User null is NOT authenticated
at 
org.jboss.jms.server.jbosssx.JBossASSecurityMetadataStore.authenticate(JBossASSecurityMetadataStore.java:223)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:93)
at 
com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:27)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:208)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:120)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:262)
at javax.management.StandardMBean.invoke(StandardMBean.java:391)
at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at $Proxy260.authenticate(Unknown Source)
at 
org.jboss.jms.server.endpoint.ServerConnectionFactoryEndpoint.createConnectionDelegateInternal(ServerConnectionFactoryEndpoint.java:233)
at 
org.jboss.jms.server.endpoint.ServerConnectionFactoryEndpoint.createConnectionDelegate(ServerConnectionFactoryEndpoint.java:171)
at 
org.jboss.jms.server.endpoint.advised.ConnectionFactoryAdvised.org$jboss$jms$server$endpoint$advised$ConnectionFactoryAdvised$createConnectionDelegate$aop(ConnectionFactoryAdvised.java:108)
at 
org.jboss.jms.server.endpoint.advised.ConnectionFactoryAdvised.createConnectionDelegate(ConnectionFactoryAdvised.java)
at 
org.jboss.jms.wireformat.ConnectionFactoryCreateConnectionDelegateRequest.serverInvoke(ConnectionFactoryCreateConnectionDelegateRequest.java:91)
at 
org.jboss.jms.server.remoting.JMSServerInvocationHandler.invoke(JMSServerInvocationHandler.java:143)
at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:891)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.local.LocalClientInvoker.invoke(LocalClientInvoker.java:106)
at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1724)
at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:629)
at 
org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.org$jboss$jms$client$delegate$ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate$createConnectionDelegate$aop(ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.java:171)
at 
org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate$createConnectionDelegate_N3019492359065420858.invokeTarget(ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate$createConnectionDelegate_N3019492359065420858.java)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
at 
org.jboss.jms.client.container.StateCreationAspect.handleCreateConnectionDelegate(StateCreationAspect.java:81)
at 
org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.jms.client.container.StateCreationAspect_z_handleCreateConnectionDelegate_31070867.invoke(StateCreationAspect_z_handleCreateConnectionDelegate_31070867.java)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at 
org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.createConnectionDelegate(ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.java)
at 

org.jboss.jms.client.JBossConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(JBossConnectionFactory.java:205)
at

org.jboss.jms.client.JBossConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(JBossConnectionFactory.java:101)
at 

org.jboss.jms.client.JBossConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(JBossConnectionFactory.java:95)
at 
org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.dlq.AbstractDLQHandler.setupDLQConnection(AbstractDLQHandler.java:137)
at 
org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.dlq.AbstractDLQHandler.setup(AbstractDLQHandler.java:83)
at 
org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.dlq.JBossMQDLQHandler.setup(JBossMQDLQHandler.java:48)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivation.setupDLQ(JmsActivation.java:413)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivation.setup(JmsActivation.java:351)
at 
org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivation$SetupActivation.run(JmsActivation.java:729)
at org.jboss.resource.work.WorkWrapper.execute(WorkWrapper.java:205)
at org.jboss.util.threadpool.BasicTaskWrapper.run(BasicTaskWrapper.java:260)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

12:01:34,859 ERROR [ExceptionUtil]
ConnectionFactoryEndpoint[jboss.messaging.connectionfactory:service=ConnectionFactory] 
createFailoverConnectionDelegate [mb-z2y983bh-1-4b8983bh-kwpr33-100j3]
```

Can somebody help ?

Comment: Hmm it looks tricky. When you copied the server to another location and run it, does the original server still runs on the same host? If so you might have some port conflict causing some service to fail to start -- and hence resulting in above error

Comment: Did anyone found other solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Solved the problem, that was happened when we are going to solve some other problem, that is com.arjuna transaction issue, in that jboss keep throwing messages non stop, to resolve that issue, some posts recommended delete the 'data' folder in jBoss, when we delete that, the hypersonic database script inside the data folder is also deleted, therefore the user Null issue came out, so what we did was restored the hypersonic db script and now it's working fine.

Comment: had the same problem and restored a known good version of the data/hypersonic directory as mentioned above and all is well.

Answer (score 1):

One other possibility is that the data-source specified in the `DatabaseServerLoginModule` bean, which is configured in "messaging-jboss-beans.xml", does not match the data-source you are using for JMS.

This would probably occur when you have replaced the "hsqldb-persistence-service.xml" file in the "deploy/messaging" directory of your server, with a customized persistence service file configured to the database you wish to use for JMS (e.g. "postgresql-persistence-service.xml").

If you do so, you will need to make sure that the value of the `dsJndiName` module option of the `DatabaseServerLoginModule` bean matches the JNDI name of the data-store in the new "-persistence-service.xml" file.  Simply replace `java:/DefaultDS` with your data-source JNDI name (e.g. `java:/MysqlDB` or whatever).

Reference: http://www.mail-archive.com/jboss-user@lists.sourceforge.net/msg59720.html

Comment: This is the case what I met.